# Find range of $y=\sin{\sqrt{x+2}}$

Tags: functions

How can I find range of this function and draw it?

$y=\sin{\sqrt{x+2}}$

I found domain 
$$x+2>=x$$
$$x>=-2$$

Comment: Range of is simply $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Well $\sqrt{x+2}$ is going to range over $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ so $\sin \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ will range over $[-1, 1]$.

Comment: What is the range of sqrt(x+2), and if that range is then fed into the sin function then what will be the output?

Answer (score 0):

The  Range of the sin function in the form $$C\sin(kx)$$ is simply:     $$[-C,C]$$  if your Domain is within the general form:                     $$[2n\pi,(2n+2)\pi], n\in \mathbb N$$ and since your domain satisfies the condition,       the range is :$$[-1,1]$$